# No admin privilege while logged in as admin

Tags: windows, user-accounts, administrator

I have windows server 2012 R2 machine.
 I am trying to run a setup that requires admin privileges, when I run it it says you need to connect as admin to setup this program, but I already logged in from admin user, also I tried 'Run as Administrator' option.

I checked the user in control panel and its connected as admin, I tried to log in as Administrator and got same error.

How I can fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do other programs that require admin access work as expected? Like, is it just a specific (setup) program your having this trouble with, or is it all programs?   If it's only a specific one, then what is it, and have you contacted the author for support?

Comment: Its specific for setup for product, but this happens in all their version...